# Expose object/methods from chrome extention to WebPage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, metamask

I'm building a chrome extension with ReactJs. I understood how content-script and background script works but, I'm not able to "share" an object/methods between the chrome extension (popup) and the current web page.

For example:

**MetaMask** inject a global **web3** object, every page can use it and trigger the pop-up chrome extension.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to put that code into a page `<script>` element, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879). It won't be able to use chrome API by default - only the [standard DOM messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198) - but you can allow chrome.runtime.sendMessage on your specific web site URL by using [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what about if I would like to inject this object in all the websites like Metamask does? In externally_connectable the URL pattern must contain at least a second-level domain

Comment: There are no magic tricks here so you'll have to use DOM messaging, see the example I've linked.

Comment: I read all the links that you provided. Are complete and well written but I'm still quite confused. If I understood correctly to receive a json from a web Page I would need: 1. An injected script  2. Send DOM messages from the injected script to the content script 3. Since I want a state persistence running Redux in the background script that receives DOM messages and saves in the chrome.storage. 4 The UI connected to the storage

Comment: Yeah it can work if in step 4 you use chrome.storage.onChanged. Or you can use sendMessage/onMessage in steps 3-4 and save to storage in step 4 if needed.